# How to insert data to postgresql database with flask - sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to insert data to postgresql database with flask.

This is a model class code that I wrote.

```
class Bet365(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "bet365s"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sports = db.Column(db.Float)
    casino = db.Column(db.Float)
    poker = db.Column(db.Float)
    games_bingo = db.Column(db.Float)
    total = db.Column(db.Float)
    withdrawal = db.Column(db.Float)
    balance = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __init__(self, sports, casino, poker, games_bingo, total, withdrawal, balance):
        self.id = id
        self.sports = sports
        self.casino = casino
        self.poker = poker
        self.games_bingo = games_bingo
        self.total = total
        self.withdrawal = withdrawal
        self.balance = balance
```

This is the snippet code which is responsible for inserting data.

```
@app.route('/testing/')
def testing():
    data_bet365 = bet365_scrapping()

    sports = float(data_bet365[0])
    casino = float(data_bet365[1])
    poker = float(data_bet365[2])
    games_bingo = float(data_bet365[3])
    total = float(data_bet365[4])
    withdrawal = float(data_bet365[5])
    balance = float(data_bet365[6])

    result_bet365 = Bet365(sports, casino, poker, games_bingo, total, withdrawal, balance)
    db.session.add(result_bet365)
    db.session.commit()
    return (jsonify(data_bet365))
```

When I run this script, I get an error like this.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'builtin_function_or_method'
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO bet365s (id, sports, casino, poker, games_bingo, total, withdrawal, balance) VALUES (%(id)s, %(sports)s, %(casino)s, %(poker)s, %(games_bingo)s, %(total)s, %(withdrawal)s, %(balance)s)']
[parameters: {'withdrawal': 0.0, 'id': <built-in function id>, 'sports': -29.94, 'total': 593.75, 'casino': 464.22, 'poker': 14.29, 'games_bingo': 145.17, 'balance': 593.75}]
```

I can't find a solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `id` as a class attribute name. You are assigning the `id` global function to `self.id` in the initializer which is the cause of the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with your column types. You're trying to insert a float into an Integer column.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please have a look again. I've updated my question. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you're trying to insert a null value into the ID column. Which should be an autogenerated field.